# AWS SDK : ECS -> createTaskSet -> how can I set last task-definition version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I want to make docker fargate task using node server

so, I use AWS node sdk like this.

```js
createTaskSet: {
            cluster: 'Cluster name',
            service: 'Service name',
            taskDefinition: 'Definition', //last definition으로 생성하는 방식
        }
```

but in here I must insert task definition name with version
so I want to this use every last version of task definition

can I use

```
{ taskDefinition: 'arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:123456789012:task-definition/MyTaskDefinition:last', }
```

like this?

Answer (score 1):

[No,](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#family) You can not mention the latest in the task definition, as it starts from 1 and after that work sequentially.

If you tried so, this will throw error naming error as `:` not allowed in family name.

**Family**

```
family
Type: string

Required: yes
```

> When you register a task definition, you give it a family, which is
>   similar to a name for multiple versions of the task definition,
>   specified with a revision number. The first task definition that is
>   registered into a particular family is given a revision of **1,** and any
>   task definitions registered after that are given a **sequential revision**
>   number.

You need to get the latest revision before using it.

You can get in AWS-cli the latest revision like

```
aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition my_task_definition_name --query 'taskDefinition.revision'
```